# Run edited python script step by step / without reloading dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, execution, python-idle

I work on a python script executing standard image recognition processing using tensorflow. Using Python 3.8, Tensorflow 2, Idle lauched from a virtual env.

Since I am following a tutorial, I would like to augment and execute my script chunk by chunk : e.g.

- write the code for the data load
- execute
- write the code for training
- execute only training (without reloading the data)

Is there a way to run a python script chunk by chunk, without restarting the idle shell, and keeping results from the previous steps?

Comment: I don't understand your actual concern. Are you working on a jupyter notebook?

Comment: No, plain Idle script

Comment: should I favor Jupyter ? let me rephrase the issue: I wish to add processing to a script step by step, and run the script step by step, without re-executing previous steps and without restarting the shell each time.

Comment: This is the behaviour of a jupyter notebook you are looking for

Comment: I assume you're concerning it in a bigger context. Is it something you've to stick with the IDLE platform or the process? If it's only the process that matters, I think, jupyter notebook or jupyter-lab is a convenient choice.

Comment: And IMO, such IDLE script is very light for such a heavy job in a bigger context.

Comment: If you are familiar with Jupiter notebook then I think you're looking for something robust but if you're not, then jupyter-notebook is the right choice for your need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Read–eval–print loop (REPL)

Yes , this is what exactly you are looking for.

This is an interactive environment that takes single user inputs, executes them, and returns the result to the user; a program written in a REPL environment is executed piecewise

There are lot of Platforms which offer this.

Jupyter Notebook (Local)

Google Colab (Online)

I prefer Google colab .

Its free & we don't have to waste our Local system Resources

Comment: Especially , if you are working on very big ML models, its better to go with a cloud platform

Answer (score 0):

In an IDLE editor, one can right click on multiple lines to add breakpoints.  Start IDLE's debugger in Shell, using Shell menu.  Run file.  Click go and execution will start and stop at first breakpoint.  Click go again to run to next breakpoint.